# Mysql, combining the two columns of the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    m.ucode_outlet AS ucode_grup,
    m.kode_outlet AS kode_grup,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE
                WHEN tot.ucode_jns_brg = '40004' THEN tot.tot_qty
                ELSE 0
            END),
            2) AS 'qty_Jeruk',
    ROUND(IFNULL(SUM(CASE
                        WHEN tot.ucode_jns_brg = '40004' THEN tot.tot_qty
                        ELSE 0
                    END) / SUM(tot.tot_qty) * 100,
                    0),
            2) AS 'psn_Jeruk',
    ROUND(SUM(CASE
                WHEN tot.ucode_jns_brg = '40005' THEN tot.tot_qty
                ELSE 0
            END),
            2) AS 'qty_Jeruk_Multi',
    ROUND(IFNULL(SUM(CASE
                        WHEN tot.ucode_jns_brg = '40005' THEN tot.tot_qty
                        ELSE 0
                    END) / SUM(tot.tot_qty) * 100,
                    0),
            2) AS 'psn_Jeruk_Multi',
    ROUND(IFNULL(SUM(tot.tot_qty), 0), 2) AS total,
    ROUND(IFNULL(SUM(tot.tot_qty) / SUM(tot.tot_qty) * 100,
                    0),
            2) AS total_psn
FROM
    tb_m_outlet m
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tp_m_tot_survey tot ON tot.kode_grup = m.kode_outlet
        AND tot.id_proc = 'C9C48EF838B76B415266C553B7FC6ECC'
WHERE
    m.ucode_div LIKE '%%'
        AND m.kode_outlet LIKE '%'
        AND m.nama_outlet LIKE '%'
GROUP BY m.ucode_outlet , m.kode_outlet , m.nama_outlet
ORDER BY m.kode_outlet
LIMIT 0 , 25
```

and a result like this:
[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwe6n.png)

how if I wanted to combine qty_jeruk and qty_jeruk_multi be qty_jeruk?

thanks

Comment: By combine, do you mean sum?

Comment: `LIKE '%'` is pretty much a useless clause. Do you mean `NOT NULL`?

Comment: @GurV yes, sum qty_jeruk & qty_jeruk_multi

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by combine, you meant sum of the two column into one, just use `IN` to add get sum of both in one column.

```
    . . .,
    ROUND(SUM(CASE
                WHEN tot.ucode_jns_brg in ('40004','40005') THEN tot.tot_qty
                ELSE 0
            END),
            2) AS 'qty_Jeruk',
    . . .
```